# Instagram API search for only public accounts

Tags: json, api, instagram, instagram-api

Is there a way to limit my query search through `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=jack&access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN` to only search for public accounts? I'm building a web application that allows me to search Instagram users and track their user information, but since I don't have access to information from private accounts, I'd like to not have them be in the query results (if possible).

I submitted the application to Instagram with scopes `basic` and `public_content`, but not `follower_list` which has access to `target_user_is_private`. I'm trying to find a way to not have to resubmit my app but use what I have to check if an account is public or private.

Any suggested hacky solutions are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this API call for each user:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

If the user is private you will get this error response:

```
{"meta": {"error_type": "APINotAllowedError", "code": 400, "error_message": "you cannot view this resource"}}
```

If its public, you will get a response like this:

```
{"meta": {"code": 200}, "data": {"username": "xxx", "bio": "xxx", "website": "", "profile_picture": "xxx", "full_name": "xxx", "counts": {"media": 22, "followed_by": 22, "follows": 22}, "id": "xxx"}}
```